# WeChat Login Integration using Chinese SDK

Tags: swift, wechat

I just want to know that what will be the 'code' parameter in WeChat login request. When i hit the request it just give me errcode: 40029 (reason : Invalid oauth code) in logs. Any help about would be appreciated.